# Security implications of storing user ID in cookie

Tags: security, cookies

What are the security implications of storing a user's unique ID in a cookie?

Logging-in is managed separately. The presence or abscense of this cookie is simply used to determine:

1. Is this a returning user?
2. If so, who did this user last login as.

These are all merely hints, the user doesn't get any more rights (before login) than a first-time visitor to the site.

#### Background

My web app front-end is implemented in Angular4 and backend is all APIs and stateless. JWTs obtained from Firebase Authentication are used for authentication. As such, when a user arrives on the home page, I have no way of knowing who the user (potentially) is and whether they are logged-in, till the time the user goes to the PWA (at `/app`).

When the user goes to the home page of my web app, I want the (stateless) server to be able to redirect them to the PWA **if** they have logged-in in the recent past (say 2 days). This can be achieved simply by the presence/ absence of a cookie, but I would also like to be able to show them a personalised greeting when `/app` page loads up.

Very open to suggestions for a better way to achieve this.

Comment: why you do not use firebase for getting id? https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users .  `var user = firebase.auth().currentUser. uid;`

Comment: @PizzaLover I want the user to be redirected transparently to PWA when they open www.mysite.com. Using JS means first loading the home page, then sending them to the PWA, which IMO makes for a slightly worse experience.